# How do I create system settings entries?

Tags: python, application-development, gtk, development, settings

I'd like to start learning how to develop system settings dialogs using Python and GTK. What is required? I know Python and GTK well. The question is how to make the dialogs themselves. Are they built into system settings, or can we attach new dialogs at runtime?

Comment: me too man I'm still newbie in python and i wanna learn it to become programmer so good you ask this question man and i wait answer too

you can look to this http://stackoverflow.com/ and this site too

http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

and this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1

this very experience site in programmer and development

Comment: sorry for last mistake and thank for nitstorm for his advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of GNOME 3.2, upstream GNOME developers dropped support for adding "external panels" to the system settings in order to more tightly control what is present there. The relevant conversation can be found, [starting with this message](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2011-May/msg00089.html), on the GNOME desktop-devel-list. Ubuntu [carries](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/precise/gnome-control-center/precise/view/head:/debian/patches/01_allow_external_panels.patch) a patch to expose this API. Here is the [relevant blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-o-system-settings).

IFAICT, python apps can not directly access the proper API, but they can still add themselves to the systems settings. They'll be show up there, but not be able to take advantage of the morphing window, bread crumbs, etc... They'll simply be called like an external program.

In order to place your app in the system settings, you need to add `X-GNOME-Settings-Panel` to the `Categories` field in your desktop file:

`Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;`

and add a new field to the desktop file:

`X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=program-icon`

It must also contain `OnlyShowIn=Unity;`

Here's an example of me forcing something in there:

[image: bzr-gtk in system settings]

Comment: Extremely weird decision. They're deliberately making sure the desktop can be customized by pretty much anyone – and bragging loudly about it – but adding configuration GUIs must be locked down completely in order to avoid any kind of divergence? Let's add a hundred different config applications instead. That makes everything more streamlined. :)